# SharePoint Timer Service is attempting to load application DLLs on non-WFE server even though Deployment Server Type is Front-end web server

Tags: owstimer

My SharePoint environment consists of 4 servers: SQL, App, WFE and non-WFE.

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service is running on App and WFE servers.

**Deployment server type: Front-end web server**

While deploying WSPs, we are getting below errors on non-WFE server.

> **OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1108)   0x5D4C  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    umbp    High The type ,
>   Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= (Id = )
>   could not be located in any loaded assembly.**
>
> **OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1108)   0x5D4C  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    7i0u    High SharePoint cannot deserialize an object
>   of type , Version=, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken= on this machine.  This typically occurs because
>   the assembly containing this type is not installed on this machine. 
>   In this case, this message can be safely ignored.  Otherwise, the
>   assembly needs to be installed on this machine in a location that can
>   be discovered by the .NET Framework.**

Why is SharePoint Timer Service (OWSTIMER.EXE) attempting to load our application DLL on non-WFE server ?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior as you have Foundation Web running on back end servers (this is a preferred architecture).

Comment: Thank you Trevor. Could you please elaborate the reason for these errors to appear on non-WFE server where none of our application specific assemblies are deployed?

Comment: From the looks of it, the solution failed to properly deploy on the back end servers. I cannot expand upon that as there's not enough logging information to see why it failed.